# How to make individual disk as logical/physical disks from HP smart array

Tags: hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

Hi I have an HP server DL Gen 8, running ubuntu Trusty. I have hpssacli running.

If you see my config below I have 6 unassigned drives. I can easily create a RAID config, that's not the issue. But basically I would like to create each unassigned drives as it's own drive. So I would like to have 6 individual drives.

Why would I want to do this... Because I'm setting up Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch can stripe it's data over physical disks. The advantage to this is that, if I lose one disk I only lose that portion of the data. Further more Elasticsearch has it's on "replication" so In reality, that specific portion would be on another server as well.

Originally I had RAID 0 setup, we lost a disk. No problem because Elasticsearch already had a backup on another server. The cool thing about setting up as individual disks, I would have only lost that one disk and not the whole and Elasticsearch would have recovered.

So all that said. Is it possible to create each one of those 6 disks as individual disks in the array? Or do I need to physically go into the box and reconnect the drives as normal disks direct to IDE not going through the controller?

sudo hpssacli ctrl all show config

```
Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 001438029ED41E0)

Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 2, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 2, OK
array A (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


  logicaldrive 1 (111.8 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, Solid State SATA, 120 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, Solid State SATA, 120 GB, OK)

unassigned

  physicaldrive 1I:2:3 (port 1I:box 2:bay 3, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:2:4 (port 1I:box 2:bay 4, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:5 (port 2I:box 2:bay 5, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:6 (port 2I:box 2:bay 6, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:7 (port 2I:box 2:bay 7, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:8 (port 2I:box 2:bay 8, Solid State SATA, 960.1 GB, OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, PLEASE, **PLEASE** don't do this as multiple RAID0 logical drives comprised of a single disk!!!

If you wish to do this properly, enable the "HBA mode" of your controller. This disables all RAID functionality of the controller. This feature is meant for the ZFS/StorageSpaces/Hadoop/vSAN solutions out there that require raw disk access.

Keep in mind that all eight disks will show up as separate devices passed through to the OS under this setup.

Comment: Ok so HBA mode will disable all of it even existing configure RAID configs?

Comment: Yep. It removes all RAID configuration.

Comment: Maybe create 3 RAID 0 arrays? I will check how advantageous ES stripping is on the community. Maybe not worth doing this. But at least 3 RAID 0 config is sensible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. SmartArray controllers don't support passthrough. Some engineers, however, use the following workaround: they create raid0 from each disk and use them. But I think this is too messy and creepy.

In the same time I don't  think that software striping in ElasticSearch is a considerable option: no software striping can be better than the hardware array.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well ES it's self has a "RAID" system. It keeps a back up of your data on another server withing it's cluster. You can even do multiple copies depending on how much resiliency you want. Essentially ES can software "RAID" at cluster level or disk level by itself.